Can I fine-tune a sentence transformer model using the transformer bib in python?
I want to use a sentence transformer model for STS task, but the sentence transformer bib is poor, so I want to use transformer bib to track my tuning using callbacks, early stopping, etc.
I know I can use a sentence transformer with transformer bib creating a pooling function, but I don't know how to introduce that function into train function.
I am thinking of overwriting the train function to modify just the part I want, like before the evaluation to compute the sentence embeddings and them send to compute the loss, but I think there must be some better ideia.
Any suggestion are welcome.
